# Set Qt default encoding to UTF-8

Tags: qt, utf-8, character-encoding, c-strings

In my Qt application my source code files are encoded as UTF-8. For the following code...

```
QMessageBox::critical(this, "Nepoznata pogreška", "Dogodila se nepoznata pogreška! Želite li zatvoriti ovaj program ?", QMessageBox::Yes, QMessageBox::No);
```

...when I show that message box, the character "š" wouldn't be displayed as "š", but as something strange. This is because Qt converts all C-strings as if they are encoded using LATIN-1. To solve this I've been using:

```
QMessageBox::critical(this, QString::fromUtf8("Nepoznata pogreška"), QString::fromUtf8("Dogodila se nepoznata pogreška! Želite li zatvoriti ovaj program ?"), QMessageBox::Yes, QMessageBox::No);
```

Is there a way to get rid of all the calls to `QString::fromUtf8()`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29485602/qt-convert-unicode-entites

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Have you tried using [QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"))](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextcodec.html#setCodecForCStrings)?

Comment: Huh, feeling stupid right now :D I didn't know that it exists ;) Thanks :)

Comment: Don't suppose something like this can be done for qt5? Seems setCodecForCStrings has been removed...

Comment: I'm afraid I can't answer for sure as I'm not working on anything which uses Qt anymore. My guess would be that Qt5 assumes all source files are UTF-8 encoded (rather than Latin-1) which would explain why they removed this. If you're having a similar problem to this then all I would just is to check all your source files are UTF-8 encoded using your favourite programmer's text editor (e.g. Notepad++)?

Answer (score 3):

`setCodecForCStrings()` had been deprecated.
Try instead,

```
QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the "guess" that "Qt5 assumes all source files are UTF-8 encoded": Thiago Macieira explains the decision made by Qt's developers [here](http://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/05/source-code-must-be-utf-8-and-qstring-wants-it/).

The assumption can be disabled with [`QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII) according to the documentation.