# Qt get accents from database

Tags: php, c++, mysql, qt

I'm not able to display accents of the database.

Example:
Database: GrÃ©goire,
     php: Grégoire,
     Qt: GrÃ©goire

How can I modify Qt output to get this "é", or event better "e", again?

My database is in `UTF8-unicode-ci`

This is my Qt code:

```
query.prepare("SELECT FIRSTNAME FROM USERS WHERE ID= :nid");
query.bindValue(":nid", id);
query.exec();

if (query.next())
{
QString str = query.value(0).toString();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705488/set-qt-default-encoding-to-utf-8

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: What database is that? Did you tell Qt to use UTF8 to encode and decode strings coming from that database? Usually it's a database option you can pass. Otherwise, you need to do manual conversions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
QString str = query.value(0).toString().toLatin1();
```

You will get `Grégoire`